# appendingTo a ListBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I'm using jQuery autocomplete with ajax and json data, but my problem comes when I append selected results to an element. ex-> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp
I can append it to ol, div, p, and ul just fine, but I want to append it to an asp:ListBox so that I can bind the results server side easier.

The function below just blanks out my ListBox.  I'm not certain why it doesn't work for appending a new element to it.

```
      function log(message) {
          $("#<%= lbx_log.ClientID %>").text(+"<asp:ListItem Text=\""+message+"\"   />").appendTo("#log");
      }
```

HTML / ASP

```
  <div >
   <asp:ListBox runat="server" id="lbx_log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content">
  <asp:ListItem Text="blank" /> 
 </asp:ListBox>
 </div>
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_back" Text="Back ←" OnClick="btn_back_Click" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_save" Text="save" OnClick="btn_save_Click" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_next" Text="Next →" OnClick="btn_next_Click" />
 </div>

</form>
 </body>
```

Comment: Since this happens 100% on the client, your server-side code is not useful is help us answer your question. Show your HTML, not your .NET code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#<%= lbx_log.ClientID %>").text(+"<asp:ListItem Text=\""+message+"\"   />"));`

This attempts to add a server-side control to the html. It doesn't work that way. asp.net converts all server controls (like `<asp:anything`) to pure html before sending the page to the client. You'll need to work with the rendered html, which you can see by viewing the page source in your browser.

Comment: Okay I think I get that.  It looks like it renders it as a selection with option values:

<SELECT id=lbx_log class=ui-widget-content style="OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 200px; WIDTH: 300px" size=4 name=lbx_log>NaNSelected: 5004377" /&gt;</SELECT>

Comment: So if I add option values to it I should be able to call them on the postback when the save button is clicked?

Comment: See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849050/problem-getting-list-box-items-added-through-jquery-in-code-behind

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know how I would go about "One way you can do this is by serializing all the Options of the Select element in a hidden input"?

Comment: I would use jQuery to iterate through all the options and get the values. You can decide how you want to serialize them. Most popular options would be a comma-delimited string or a JSON object or array.